# Backgroundworker with recursive DirectorCopy function

Tags: c#, .net, recursion, backgroundworker

I spent almost three days with this below, so I finally ended up here.

I have a function (from MSDN) which copies a folder with it's every file and subfolder. First it copies the main folder's files, then calls itself on each subfolder.

Here it is:

```
private void DirectoryCopy(string sourceDirName, string destDirName)
    {
        // Get the subdirectories for the specified directory.
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);
        DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();

        if (!dir.Exists)
        {
            throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(
                "Source directory does not exist or could not be found: "
                + sourceDirName);
        }

        // If the destination directory doesn't exist, create it. 
        if (!Directory.Exists(destDirName))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
        }

        // Get the files in the directory and copy them to the new location.
        FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            string temppath = System.IO.Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name);
            file.CopyTo(temppath, false);
        }

        // Copying subdirectories and their contents to new location. 
        foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs)
        {
            string temppath = System.IO.Path.Combine(destDirName, subdir.Name);
            DirectoryCopy(subdir.FullName, temppath, copySubDirs);
        }
    }
```

The problem is that it could take a long time therefore I tried to use BackgroundWorker, but I don't know how to place it in it's DoWork event.

If I place the first DirectoryCopy call in the DoWork event, can't handle the Cancel event:

```
private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        if (worker.CancellationPending)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }
        DirectoryCopy(sourcePath, destPath, true);
    }
```

sourcePath and destPath are members of my class.

Any tips how can I handle the worker's Cancel event in the DirectoryCopy?
Or any other tips to make it working?

Thanks!

Comment: Try adding a parameter like Func<bool> cancel to DirectoryCopy method and call with () => worker.CancellationPending and check it inside the loop

Comment: Try passing both worker and and e to DirectoryCopy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I haven't worked with `BackgroundWorker` yet, looking at your question - a quick ( might be ill-logical ) suggestion would be to pass  `DoWorkEventArgs e` inside the DirectoryCopy method 
like

`DirectoryCopy (sourcePath, destPath, true, worker , e)`

where BackgroundWoker worker , DoWorkEventArgs e
and handle it whatever way you want it inside.

Example :

```
if (worker.CancellationPending)
     {
        // your code
        e.Cancel = true;
     }
```

Hope this  helps!

Comment: It didnt work, but as @Blam said, if I pass both `DoWorkEventArgs e` and `BackgroundWorker worker`, it works great!

Comment: @AdamMezovari : Thanks, editted my answer based on your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

The best and easiest approach here is to use `Directory.EnumerateDirectories(,,)`.

This remove the recursion from your code and makes it easier to stop.

```
foreach(var dir in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(sourceDir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
{    
   foreach(var file in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(dir, "*.*")
   {
     if (worker.CancellationPending)
     {
        e.Cancel = true;
        return;
     }

     // copy file
   }      
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The only problem that I did not mention it has to run on windows 2000 as well, therefore I use .NET 2.0 and as I see, `Directory.EnumerateDirectories()` only supported from 4.0.